# AJAX always send row one Value from table to Servlet JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I tried to send Value from Table to Servlet. But its always take value from the first row. my value came from **"data-whatever"** attribute in Anchor tag on the table cell.

Here is my Table HTML Code

```
            <%                    
                int i = 1;
                Session s = DB.getSession();
                Criteria cr = s.createCriteria(Branch.class);

                List <Branch> branch = cr.list();

                for (Branch b: branch) {  %>

                    <tr>
                <td><%= i++ %></td>
                <td><%= b.getBranchNo() %></td>
                <td><%= b.getBranchName() %></td>
                <td><%= b.getContact1() %></td>
                <td><%= b.getContact2() %></td>
                <td><%= b.getCity() %></td>
                <td><%= b.getIsActive() %></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" id="viewModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<%= b.getIdBranch() %>" onclick="load()">View</a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#">Delete</a></div>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <%        
                    }

            %>


        </tbody>
```

And Here is my Script

```
var BranchID = $('#viewModal').attr('data-whatever');

       $('#branchcode1').attr('value',BranchID);

       $.ajax({

            url : '../BranchViewAJAX',
            data : { branchID : BranchID },

        success : function(responseText) {


            $('#bNo').text(responseText);

            BranchID = null;
        }


    });
```

Here is the Table [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeH6S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple:

> **but you must know the priciple first**:
>
> ID an CLASS is different. ID is unique so you must use 1 specific ID to only 1 element. CLASS is general. you can use class in a lot of element

so remove `id="viewModal"` and add `class="viewModal"` in your code, so your code will look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="viewModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<%= b.getIdBranch() %>" onclick="load()">View</a></div>
```

then write script to check this

```
$('body').on('click', '.viewModal', function(){
    var branchID = $(this).attr('data-whatever');
    alert(branchID);//do your ajax
});
```

but if you want still using `id="viewModal"` like this

```
<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="viewModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<%= b.getIdBranch() %>" onclick="load()">View</a></div>
```

we can use this selector:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div[id="viewModal"]', function(){
    var branchID = $(this).attr('data-whatever');
    alert(branchID); //do your ajax
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I just fixed my code with your solution.

Comment: dont forget to check as an answer if this solved your problem

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks